# PHP check if two keywords occur in String

Tags: php, preg-match-all

my challange explained on the following example: The keyword combination "gaming notebook" is given.

I want to check whether the two keywords occur in a string. The challange is that the string could look like this:

"Nice Gaming Notebook"
"Notebook for Gaming"
"Notebook for extreme Gaming"

I want my function to return true for all of the three strings. There is a tolerance of 3-4 words that can be between the word combination and as the examples show, I want it to work if the keywords are switched.

So my approach was the following, but it does not seem to work:

```
$keyword = strtolower("gaming notebook");
$parts = explode(" ", $keyword);

$string = strtolower("Which notebook for good gaming performance");
//point to end of the array
end($parts);
//fetch key of the last element of the array.
$lastElementKey = key($parts);
//iterate the array
$searchExpression = "";
foreach($parts as $k => $v) {
    if($k != $lastElementKey) {
        $searchExpression .= $v . "|";
    } else {
        $searchExpression .= $v;
    }
}

if(preg_match_all('#\b('. $searchExpression .')\b#', $string, $matches) > 0) {
    echo "Jep, keyword combination is in string";
} else {
    echo "No, keyword combination is not in string";
}
```

Comment: Is the tolerance a requirement?

Comment: Hey Robbie, yep it should return true even if one or two words (or 20 chars) are between the two keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use something like CMU Sphinx or a natural language index in your database.  (See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)  Doing a quick search of php libraries turned up "nlp-tools/nlp-tools," however, I have never used a pure php solution to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `preg_match_all` and `array_intersect` functions:

```
$keywordStr = "gaming notebook";
$string = "Which notebook for good gaming performance,it's my notebook";
$keywords = explode(" ", $keywordStr);
$parts = implode("|", $keywords);

preg_match_all("/\b$parts\b/i", $string, $matches);
// matched items should contain all needed keywords
if (count($keywords) == count(array_intersect($keywords, $matches[0]))) {
    echo "Jep, keyword combination is in string";
} else {
    echo "No, keyword combination is not in string";
}
```

Comment: Thank you Roman,
now it checks perfectly if all the keywords are in the string.
Do you have an idea how the script can only return true, if not more then two or three words are between the keywords.
Let's say: "notebook for exreme gaming" returns true, but "notebook for a lot of extensive gaming" does return false.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$keyword = strtolower("gaming notebook");
$string = strtolower("Which notebooks for good gaming performance");
function check($keyword,$string){
    $parts = explode(' ',$keyword);
    $result = false;
    $pattern = implode('|',$parts);
    preg_match_all("(\b{$pattern}\b)",$string,$matches);
    if(isset($matches[0])){
       return true;
    }

    return false;
}

var_dump(check($keyword, $string));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$reg = "/(?:\b$kw1(?:\s+\w+){0,4}\s+$kw2\b)|(?:\b$kw2(?:\s+\w+){0,4}\s+$kw1\b)/";
if (preg_match($reg, $string)) {
    echo "OK\n";
} else {
    echo "KO\n";
}
```

This will echo OK when the 2 keywords occur in the string, in any order and separated by at most 4 words.

**Explanation:**

```
/
  (?:               : non capture group
    \b$kw1          : keyword 1
    (?:\s+\w+){0,4} : followed by 0 to 4 other word
    \s+             : space(s)
    $kw2\b          : keyword 2
  )
|
  (?:               : non capture group
    \b$kw2          : keyword 2
    (?:\s+\w+){0,4} : followed by 0 to 4 other word
    \s+             : space(s)
    $kw1\b          : keyword 1
  )
/
```