# Regex to match words in good order

Tags: regex

I want to program an alert system by checking if several lists of keywords are present in one address.

This is my two variables in PHP :

```
$MyAdress = "210, street Cardinal Avenue, Canada"; (to testing)
$SearchAdress = "210 Cardinal Avenue"; (from my list of possible keywords to find)
```

I want to test if my SearchAddress is present in my address and check if words are in the good position, how is it possible ?

With Regex ? (It's always been gobbledegook to me)

By example "210 Cardinal Avenue" return TRUE
but "210 Avenue Cardinal" must to return FALSE.

This code [PHP check if two keywords occur in String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736563/php-check-if-two-keywords-occur-in-string/37736784#37736784) is interesting, but the order is not respected.

Also I resolved problem to transform text in lower and replace foreign characters in a String.

Comment: The answer that you found also can be used to your question, you just need to read the documentation about the function. There is a flag you can use to respect order: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the words into `\b` [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and concatenate them with [`.+?`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy)

```
(?i)\b210\b.+?\bcardinal\b.+?\bavenue\b
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/G9ZFbF/2) or a [PHP demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##XZFfa8IwFMXf8ykuWkjLgt326obIXvYyEPY4h6TmaoPNnyVpXRn77F1sq@IgDzfnnNzfgdjSdt3TYvW6IiTPIaAP4IOTeu9J8tYuhUPv4Rk@Jo8P9@xkIQZ44U5IzStYNqhrZFHQXPAJO6X@u6M6XC7m5HPeE@UOWlODRhQQDBS1rOJQIlgeAjoNO2cUHLA9Gic8cOd4y6DWW6MU6kCmycWLLWkkUUa3IySOvMfSSJsmDvf4HWM0Xxd0JpWtjMCUrovZ3SIqbNi@Udym1Mbw5qs2AaN@YWTZLMZzSYfyoZQe4inN8aZzZczBQyUPSG6gsd0IOzccr0PL8@adcci3ZXr9gOU7JE0GPwSg4W4jamXTpGGQFsZUWd9V8XB60uNYDGdz8ku67g8) (used `i` [flag](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for *ignorecase*)

---

This would match the words in sequence with [one or more](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) of [any characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) in between.
To also match `210CardinalAvenue` drop word boundaries between and use `.*?` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/OBR847/1)).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will study that